# Dificuldades em conectar Javascript com HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

Há alguns meses fiz um curso para me inserir no mercado de trabalho como "Front End", aprendi o que era necessário, mas agora para botar em prática o Javascript está complicado, pois na teoria sei bastante coisa com o Javascript, mas na hora de ligar estas coisas com o DOM tá difícil.

Tens alguma dica ou forma de estudar?

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Você quer dizer como incluir javascript no HTML? O local onde devem ser incluídos os scripts na página HTML?

Comment: O que realmente você precisa fazer ?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, tente elaborá-la melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para incluir JavaScript numa página HTML use a tag `<script type="text/javascript"> seu script </script>`. Tudo o que estiver dentro destas tags será interpretado como linguagem JavaScript. No HTML5 basta `<script></script>`.

Se você incluir dentro das tags `<head></head>`, o script será executado antes da página ser exibida (ou seja, se não carregar o script, a página não abre, mas quando abrir, já abre com o JavaScrit funcionando 100%), e se incluir dentro do `<body></body>` será executado durante a exibição.

Você também pode incluir o JavaScript através de um arquivo externo, linkando ele entre as tags `<head>`:

```
<script src="_javascript/meu_script.js"></script>
```

Um exemplo de utilização do Javascript para manipular um elemento do DOM (o script abre uma div de acordo com a escolha de um `button radio`):

```js
   var esconderradio = function(var1, var2) {
    
        if (var1) {
            document.getElementById(var2).style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(var2).style.display = "none";
        }
    };
```

```html
   <label class="radio" for="Csaldsim">
        Sim
        <input type="radio" id="Csaldsim" name="radio" onclick="esconderradio(true, 'salvenc')"></label>
    <label class="radio" for="Csaldnao"  onclick="esconderradio(false, 'salvenc')">
        Não
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="Csaldnao" onclick="onclick="esconderradio('Csaldim', 'salvenc')"></label>

<br>

    <div  class=" col-md-3 panel panel-default" id="salvenc" style="display:none;">
        <label class="btn" for="Csalvenc">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Tsalvenc" id="Csalvenc"></label>
    </div>
```

Para estudar Javascript sugiro o [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/pt-BR/learn).